# No me funciona los ng-template en angular

Tags: angular

resulta que estoy aprendiendo angular y tengo el siguiente código en mi archivo ts:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego en mi archivo de vista tengo el siguiente código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo anterior parece que no me está funcionando. Alguna ayuda de por qué me pasa?Hasta ahora yo veo que todo está bien. El problema es que el programa no me entra en la condición y por lo tanto no se vé nada.

Comment: Por favor, añade el código en formato de texto, no compartas imágenes con código ya que dificulta a la hora de leer y, por ende, de poder ayudarte. Edita tu pregunta copiando y pegando tu código, y elimina las imágenes.

Comment: Seria muy recomendable pusieras también lo que aparece en la consola del navegador.

Answer (score 0):

Primero, te recomendaría que no inicialices en el constructor variables que se usen en la vista. Es mejor hacerlo en el ngOnInit()

Segundo, ¿podrías poner si te da algún error en la consola del navegador? Eso ayuda siempre a identificar mejor los errores.

La condición está bien, lo único que veo raro es el **click()="setIdentificado"** que tienes en el button. Debería ser **(click)="setIdentificado"** y probablemente esto sea el problema.

Saludos y espero que sea de ayuda.